# Target class [Database\Seeders\TagsIndexDeleteSeeder] does not exist in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, lumen

I have created 2 sub folders just to categorise the seeders files. Other files seems to be working but seeder files which are there in sub folders fails.

It works on my local system but fails on server. I even tried `composer dump-autoload` without success.

Added `namespace Database\Seeders;` in all seeders files.

When I try to run the below command getting the below error.

```sh
php artisan db:seed --class=TagsIndexDeleteSeeder
```

```
In Container.php line 832:
                                                                         
  Target class [Database\Seeders\TagsIndexDeleteSeeder] does not exist.  
                                                                         

In Container.php line 830:
                                                               
  Class Database\Seeders\TagsIndexDeleteSeeder does not exist 



Class Database\Seeders\TagsIndexCreateSeeder located in ./database/seeders/TagsEsSeeder/TagsIndexCreateSeeder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class Database\Seeders\TagsIndexDeleteSeeder located in ./database/seeders/TagsEsSeeder/TagsIndexDeleteSeeder.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
```

**TagsIndexDeleteSeeder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders\TagsEsSeeder;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TagsIndexDeleteSeeder extends Seeder
{
    public function run()
    {
       
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Does you composer.json contains this line? https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/composer.json#L40 Also _It works on my local system but fails on server_ A common error when you work on Windows and the server is Linux is often a uppercase/lowercase since Windows is not case senstive.

Answer (score 0):

The namespace for your files is wrong.

- The files inside the folder `database/seeders/TagsEsSeeder` need to have `namespace Database\Seeders\TagsEsSeeder;`.
- The files inside the folder `database/seeders/UserEsSeeder` need to have `namespace Database\Seeders\UserEsSeeder;`.

So as an example for the file `TagsIndexCreateSeeder`:

```php
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders\TagsEsSeeder;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class TagsIndexCreateSeeder extends Seeder
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: getting this error `Target class [Database\Seeders\TagsIndexDeleteSeeder] does not exist.`

Comment: Show the complete content of your TagsIndexDeleteSeeder file. Edit your question and post the code inline there.

Comment: updated the post with TagsIndexDeleteSeeder code